# Request permission on PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I want to check wheter the user have granted permission for my application to use **PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS**. What I am currently doing is this:

```
// Control that the required permissions is instantiated!
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS}, MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

I have implemented the requestPermissions as described in the Android Developer section and it is working just fine for **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION**.

But when my application request permissions it only shows the **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** permission and not the **PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS** can anyone explain why? And if so, give a solution to how I could do it?

I want both permissions to show up in a dialog box like this:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't request the `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` at runtime like you do with a dangerous permission. The user need to manually grant the permission through the Settings application as explained in the `UsageStatsManager` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html):

> This API requires the permission
>   android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level
>   permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However,
>   declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user
>   of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

You can directly open the `Apps with usage access` activity with this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
```

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics) you can find an example of a basic app that shows how to use App usage statistics API.

Comment: Yeah I am already doing that. I am just annoyed with my users having to open the setting app. But thanks for clearing that up.