# How request UsageStatsManager permission like a runtime permission?

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I want know if exists some solution to request `UsageStatsManager` permission like a normal runtime permission, where user can allow or deny the access?

[image]

i not want redirect user to the list **Apps with usage access** and still select my app to check this permission like this following code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(); 
 intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36822181/9214428) is a useful explanation where says that this is a permission conceded only to system apps (then this probably can prevent user interation with the list **Apps with usage access** like i want).