# How can I open the user access permissions for a particular app

Tags: android, android-intent, usagestatsmanager

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36822181/848850) shows how to open the general Usage access settings for all apps:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
```

How can I open the Usage access settings for a specific app on that list directly?

I tried

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS).putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName()));
```

but this does the same as the previous line. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me (tested on Android 9 / 10):

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
intent.data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: This opens the general app settings for some reason, not specifically "Usage data access" as it's labeled on my Samsung Tab A running .

Answer (score 1):

**Open your app settings screen Then click on Permissions because there is no intent to go directly to the Permissions screen.**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
    Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but Usage access permissions are not actually listed there (at least not in Android 9).

Comment: Hey, ok sorry did not check API compatibility - apparently this only works starting with Android 10.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in an activity -

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
    startActivity(intent);
```